# Чем упаковать программу, чтобы ее не взломали?

Tags: delphi, поиск-программ

Чем упаковать программу, чтобы её не крякнули?

Comment: Вы можете стать борцом с киберпреступностью. Узнаете, что кто-то крякнул (или кукарекнул) Вашу программу -- и в турму его. ст. 273 УК РФ (ежели склероз мне не изменяет)

Comment: Я задал вопрос, значит да, я думаю что моя программа кому-то нужна.

Comment: При достаточной квалификации и желании -- взломают, как бы Вы ни старались. А чем Вам не нравится защита закона? Сообщили в правоохранительные органы (тем более, Вы -- автор и правообладатель), и пусть они разбираются. Может, на отступных заработаете...

Comment: Упаковщиком.
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: от упаковщиков толку мало, только экономия места, они распаковываются практически все в два клика. Для защиты нужен протектор. Лучше свой, т.к. большинство стандартных уже тоже разообраны и практически в 95% случаев снимаются автоскриптами. Учтите, что идеальная защита - защита, которую нужно минимум 1 раз купить. После покупки, при попадении ключа в правильные руки любая защита снимается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для защиты кода от взлома, попробуйте рассмотреть **[VMProtect](http://vmpsoft.com/)**, на основе виртуализации исполняемого кода, вполне надежная защита со своими плюсами и минусами.

Это вполне качественный отечественный продукт на мировом рынке, ещё он платный. Удобство представляют [уже готовые реализации](http://www.vmpsoft.com/forum/) для выдачи серийников или подключений к системам взимания платежей и т.д.

---

Если вас интересует **упаковщик**, используйте [**Inno Setup**](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inno_Setup), свободный продукт с большими и гибкими возможностями, если не ошибаюсь, можно задавать пароль (серийник) для произведения установки конечными Пользователями.

Comment: хороший совет, протектор достаточно пакостный, не каждый способен бросить ему вызов... Но в определённых кругах его всё-таки разобрали и могут довольно быстро снять, т.ч. как правильно написали в комментариях к вопросу, универсальной панацеи нет

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать ASProtect + что-то своё добавить в программу.

Comment: Грамотно прикрученный ASProtect довольно сложно сломать. Другой вопрос, что часто возникают проблемы с UAC и прочими современными наворотами Винды. Приходится включать голову.

Comment: Ни разу не возникало проблем с UAC или антивирусами. Можно подробнее и/или примеры?

Comment: Речь идёт об ASprotect 2.x SKE

Если с программой работает юзер без админских прав, а регает её админ, пользователь не увидит ключ. 
Локацию сохранения ключа в реестре изменить нельзя.
У нас там был навороченный механизм многопользовательской регистрации. Для некоторых клиентов приходилось извращаться.

Comment: Совсем не так. Ключ можно хранить где угодно, в любой ветке реестра. Можно в файле рядом с программой. Храни 2 файла: для админа и для юзверя.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше больше разнообразных проверок в коде сделать, что бы крекер запарился их отключать. Но если софт реально нужный-то взломают твою программку, что бы ты не предпринимал